# Is there a general algebraic notion of the chain rule?

Tags: derivatives, field-theory

To motivate this, I should explain that I have been studying differential fields, i.e. fields endowed with a differentiation operator such that $(a+b)'=a'+b'$ and $(ab)'=a'b+ab'$.

Using these rules, a lot of the standard differentiation rules that you would expect can be easily proven:
$$ (a^n)'=na^{n-1}a'$$
$$ \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)'=\frac{a'b-b'a}{b^2}$$

The field is not required to be a field of functions; however, I have found that every instance of a differential field that I have seen (other than any field being endowed with the trivial derivation $\forall x,x'=0$ has been some sort of function field (usually a $F(x)$ for some field $F$ or something like the field of meromorphic functions).

I was then curious if the chain rule could somehow carry over, and this got me thinking about what a functions field really was. I guess my question can then be formulated:

Let $K$ be a field. Now let $F$ be a set of functions which map from $K$ into $K$ such that $F$ forms a field under point-wise addition and multiplication and $F$ is closed under composition and differentiation. My question is, what conditions must we place on $K$ or $F$ for it to be true that whenever $f,g\in F$, the following holds:
$$ (f \circ g)'=(f' \circ g)\cdot g'$$

The only proof I have ever seen of the chain rule is done by analytical means; however, I suspect that it can be proven for fields like $Q(x)$ using purely algebraic means. Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: You never define $G$. What is it? If it's $F$, then you should require that $F$ be closed under composition, and also define what you mean by the derivative of an arbitrary map from a field to itself.

Comment: In any case, fieldness is a red herring. The general notion is called a derivation ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra) ) and it can be defined in great generality, on arbitrary (not necessarily commutative or even associative) algebras. For associative algebras the chain rule holds in the following sense: if $R$ is an algebra over a field $k$, $r \in R$ an element, $D : R \to R$ a $k$-linear derivation, and $f$ a polynomial over $k$, then $D(f(r)) = f'(r) D(r)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you I left out being closed under composition, and yes the $G$ was a typo. I will take a look at your link.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Also, that is very interesting, but I am wondering, what if $f$ is not a polynomial over $k$? Take, for example, $k$ to be the set of meromorphic functions, and $f$ is the natural logarithm. The chain rule still holds then.

Comment: I guess another interesting question would then be, in what scenarios does the chain rule not hold?

Comment: Natural logarithm is not defined as a function from the meromorphic functions (on some domain) to itself, because $\ln(0)$ is undefined, and  $\ln(f)$ has a branch point at a zero of $f$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused about something: how do you even define the derivative of an arbitrary function $f: K\rightarrow K$? Even if we assume $K$ carries a differential operator, it's not clear to me how to get a notion of derivative on $F$ (well, you could define $f'$ to be the map $x\mapsto (f(x))'$, but I strongly suspect you don't want this). Are we assuming $K$ comes with a topology?

Comment: My idea was that any operator which satisfied $(f+g)'=f'+g'$ and $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$ where the addition and multiplication are pointwise would count as a differentiation operator. I did not have a specific derivative in mind, but rather I was just thinking about any derivation on the set of functions (although hopefully it would agree with the derivation of the underlying field).